# How to merge dataframe A and B to get the dataframe as the dataframe C

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to merge dataframe A and B to get the dataframe as the dataframe C

DF A:

```
      X       Y  
    0-10   10-25 
    10-20  25-75 
    20-30  75-150
```

DF B:

```
Binned Name Value
0-10     X    20
10-20    X    100
20-30    X    200
10-25    Y    90
25-75    Y    25
75-150   Y    90
```

DF C:

```
    X    X_Val     Y     Y_Val  
   0-10   20      10-25   90
  10-20   100     25-75   25
  20-30   200     75-150  30
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
# pivot B to make columns X & Y
df_b = df_b.pivot_table(values=['Value'], index=['Binned'], columns=['Name']).reset_index()
df_b.columns = ['Binned', 'X', 'Y']

# merge X & Y cols sequentially
df_c = pd.merge(df_a, df_b[['Binned', 'X']], how='left', left_on=['X'], right_on=['Binned'], suffixes=('', '_Val'))
df_c = pd.merge(df_c, df_b[['Binned', 'Y']], how='left', left_on=['Y'], right_on=['Binned'], suffixes=('', '_Val'))
df_c = df_c[['X', 'X_Val', 'Y', 'Y_Val']]

#        X  X_Val       Y  Y_Val
# 0   0-10   20.0   10-25   90.0
# 1  10-20  100.0   25-75   25.0
# 2  20-30  200.0  75-150   90.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
#reshape dfA for inner merge with dfB
df1 = dfA.melt(var_name='Name', value_name='Binned')

df = dfB.merge(df1)

#reshape for multiple columns by groups
df = (df.set_index([df.groupby('Name').cumcount(), 'Name'])
        .unstack()
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
        .rename(columns={'Binned':'','Value':'_Val'})
        .swaplevel(0,1,axis=1))
df.columns = df.columns.map(''.join)

print (df)
       X  X_Val       Y  Y_Val
0   0-10     20   10-25     90
1  10-20    100   25-75     25
2  20-30    200  75-150     90
```

Comment: Yes, it works well but I couldn't check it as it is not the same sorting order of data frame A

Comment: Need to preserve the df  order, as I need merge other data frame with same order

Comment: Do you think order orf rows in `X` in `dfA` ? `merge` sorting data, so if unique values in `X` in `dfA` add to solution `dfnew = df.set_index('X').reindex(dfA['X']).reset_index()`

Answer (score 0):

Write sql query for each name

```
    df1=spark.sqlContext("select * from DF_B where name='X'")
    df2=spark.sqlContext("select * from DF_B where name='Y'")
```

Create one column for each data frame with row id

```
    df1_id= df1.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
    df2_id= df2.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
```

Now we can join the both dataframe df1_id and df2_id.

```
    df1_id.join(df2_id,"id").show()
```